# How to pass string variable to scala reflection typecheck quasiquote?

Tags: scala

I try to resolve full path of a class based on generic type taken from reflection api.
For instace for List[Int] i have only "Int" String. Here is working example

```
val toolBox=universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
toolBox.typecheck(q"??? : Int").tpe.typeSymbol.fullName
```

full name is java.lang.Int as supposed.

But after pass type in form of variable to quasiQuote 
full name is always java.langString no matter what was under t variable.
I suppose that ${t} is resolved to expression of String type.

```
val t = "Int"
toolBox.typecheck(q"??? : ${t}").tpe.typeSymbol.fullName
```

Thanks for help,
Kris

Comment: `java.lang.Int` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to splice the name of a type into a quasiquote, that should be a `TypeName`, not a `String`.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

scala> val toolBox = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()
toolBox: scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox[reflect.runtime.universe.type] = scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxFactory$ToolBoxImpl@42c2120c

scala> val t = "Int"
t: String = Int

scala> toolBox.typecheck(q"??? : ${TypeName(t)}").tpe.typeSymbol.fullName
res0: String = scala.Int
```